# how hide/show dynamically created nodes in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, nodes

I have created multiple nodes dynamically. Now, I have to find specific node when it is clicked, it must hide all other node in the pane. Also, When I click it again it should display the hidden node.

[image]
For example,In the attached image, the down-arrow icon on root node is clicked, it must hide all other nodes and when it is clicked second time, it must show the hidden nodes again.
This how I am creating the buttons.

```
  Node_Basic_Event_Node anode = new Node_Basic_Event_Node(calcNode_Id("Basic_Event_Node"), "Basic_Event_Node", editorName, editorType); anode.relocate(50, 50); elementsContent.getChildren().add(anode);
```

Now, How I can hide nodes when clicking on root node's down-arrow icon in the image? I tried this sample of code but it is hiding all nodes including "root node"

```
    Pane elementsContent = (Pane) getParent();
    for (Node node : elementsContent.getChildren()) {
            node.managedProperty().set(true);
            node.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: from your comment to the answer: _However, In my case i have it is not only button, .._ that's exactly why you must add __all relevant__ details to the question ;) best with an example demonstrating the exact problem ...

Answer (score 1):

I am not absolutly sure where your problem exactly is, but I created a small example which will hopefully help you. The button which should not change visibility (here: certain text) is simply filtered out every time.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Random;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox vBox = new VBox();

        Random random = new Random();
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(10);

        String chosen = "The Chosen One", simple = "Simple Button";

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            Button button = new Button(simple);

            if (i == randomIndex)
                button.setText(chosen);

            vBox.getChildren().add(button);

            button.setOnAction(event -> {

                Button clickedButton = (Button) event.getSource();

                if (clickedButton.getText().equals(chosen)) {

                    // Save visibility status of the simple buttons:
                    Optional<Boolean> visible = vBox.getChildren().stream()
                            .filter(node -> node instanceof Button)
                            .map(node -> (Button) node)
                            .filter(btn -> !btn.getText().equals(chosen))
                            .findFirst().map(Button::isVisible);

                    // Change visibility of the buttons except the filtered chosen one:
                    vBox.getChildren().stream()
                            .filter(node -> node instanceof Button)
                            .map(node -> (Button) node)
                            .filter(btn -> !btn.getText().equals(chosen))
                            .forEach(btn -> btn.setVisible(!btn.isVisible()));

                    // Change the (not so) chosen one:
                    if (visible.isPresent() && !visible.get()) {
                        int nextIndex = random.nextInt(10);
                        for (int j = 0; j < vBox.getChildren().size(); j++) {
                            if (vBox.getChildren().get(j) instanceof Button) {
                                Button btn = (Button) vBox.getChildren().get(j);
                                if (j == nextIndex)
                                    btn.setText(chosen);
                                else
                                    btn.setText(simple);
                            }
                        }
                        vBox.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for time to write an answer. However, In my case i have it is not only button, I have textfield, flowpane and imageview in same node. Therefore, I am unable to parse the node type with any scene like button or imageview.

Comment: You are welcome. I think it is not a problem when you have different types of nodes in your elementsContent pane, because you can ask the type of the node with "node instanceof Button".

Comment: Not sure what all this string comparison stuff is supposed to do, but if you know the button that needs to be visible in the end, why not just make all nodes invisible and then make the one that should be kept visible visible again...

Comment: @fabian can you please little explain, the invisible and visible technique. because i used lookup technique but it could not solve the problem